# How do I retrieve information off of a web page using python and make the code spit it out

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I am trying to make a code that searches for a movie online, and spits out information. So far I have used selenium to interact with the web, but I get as far as locating the right element. I designated this by saying:
`synopsis = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movieSynopsis"]')`

```
print(synopsis)
```

Problem is, whenever I do that, it doesn’t print out the text, but I get bunch of stuff that I don't want. This is the output I receive:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3ba7827a8523622eb0e81cbe1d20ecbe", element="0.234680993959405-1")>
```

How do I make it so that it prints the information I want.
By the way, I am trying to make it print the synopsis of Deadpool on rotten tomatoes, URL is --> https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/deadpool

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please format your post, to actually formulate a question? Also please provide the output of the current situation, as it may help people answering your question

Comment: Don't ever ever use ids(@id) to search for anything.  You'll run in to problems everywhere unless you're coding to it . To bypass google coding against it with random div ids, i've sent raw keystrokes.  To bypass emberjs sending raw ids, i use css and xpath selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Check out BeautifulSoup it's a python library built specifically to help webscrapers parse html. I think it will make this a lot easier for you.